# Riemann-Stieltjes intgeraiton and relation to the Riemann Integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I'm trying to find a proof of this relation of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral to the Riemann integral:

$$\int f\ dg = \int fg'dx$$

Wikipedia seems to [miss a proof of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral) and I can't find it anywhere, I've googled "Riemann-Stieltjes integral pdf" and found dozens of them, but couldn't find a proof of it in any of them. I've found a mention to it in the [wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesIntegral.html) but couldn't find the book that is linked in the references. Could somebody present me a proof or an idea of how to prove it?

I've found this:

[image]

on the book "A garden of integrals".

I think the last line was suppose to go to $0$, is it true? And how the uniform continuity and boudedness of $\phi'$ will do it?

Answer (score 1):

The $dg$ term is a weight for the integral, and is technically a function of $x$. For the Riemann integral, a special kind of R-S integral, this function is just
$$
g(x)=x
$$ 
So the relation really just comes from applying the differential operator $d$ to the $g(x)$ weight function
$$
dg(x)=g'*dx
$$
By the chain rule. Note that in the case of the Riemann integral this works out to be 
$$
d(x)=dx
$$
as you'd hope.

Comment: That's weird, it doesn't look like a proof, could you be more clear?

Comment: What part is confusing?

Comment: What does it mean "applying the differential operator to the $g(x)$ weight function? Also, I didn't even define the chain rule for a Stieltjes integral, so how can I apply it? I must, somehow, use the sum definition and arrive at the riemann sum definition of integral. Do you have any place that I can look or do you know how to do it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by chain rule for stieltjes integral, it is the same as in the rest of calculus. The differential operator being a linear functional from the set of functions to itself. You use it when you take implicit derivatives

Comment: And no, such a proof sounds too painful. Good luck!

Comment: i've found something intersting, could you take a look at the update?

Answer (score 1):

I'm operating on the assumption here that $g'$ is continuous.

By definition,
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dg(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_i)[g(x_i+\Delta x)-g(x_i)],
$$
where
$$
x_i:=a+i\Delta x,\qquad \Delta x:=\frac{b-a}{n}
$$
Note that we've committed a common abuse of notation here: both $x_i$ and $\Delta x$ actually depend on $n$, although the notation doesn't make this clear.

Now, on the other hand,
$$
\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_i)g'(x_i)\Delta x.
$$
Let's focus on the quantities inside the limits for now.  For any fixed $n$, let $D_n$ be the difference
$$
D_n:=\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_i)[g(x_i+\Delta x)-g(x_i)]\right]-\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_i)g'(x_i)\Delta x\right]
$$
Note that if we assume $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$; so, there exists some $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\lvert D_n\rvert&=\left\lvert\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_i)\left[g'(x_i)-(g(x_i+\Delta x)-g(x_i))\right]\right\rvert\\
&\leq\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left\lvert f(x_i)[g'(x_i)\Delta x-(g(x_i+\Delta x)-g(x_i))]\right\rvert\\
&\leq M\Delta x\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left\lvert g'(x_i)-\frac{g(x_i+\Delta x)-g(x_i)}{\Delta x}\right\rvert
\end{align*}
$$
Now, for each $i$, there is $c_i\in[x_i,x_i+\Delta x]$ so that 
$$
\frac{g(x_i+\Delta x)-g(x_i)}{\Delta x}=g'(c_i),
$$
so that we can write
$$
\lvert D_n\rvert\leq M\Delta x\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left\lvert g'(x_i)-g'(c_i)\right\rvert.
$$

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Now, $\lvert x_i-c_i\rvert\leq\Delta x$ for all $i$.  And, because $g'$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, it is uniformly continuous. So, there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \lvert g'(x)-g'(y)\rvert<\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)M}.
$$
(That choice will make sense in a moment.)  Choose $n$ large enough that $\Delta x<\delta$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\lvert D_n\rvert&\leq M\Delta x\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lvert g'(x_i)-g'(c_i)\rvert\\
&\leq M\Delta x\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)M}\\
&=M\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}\cdot n\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)M}\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}
$$
So, the difference between the Rieman-Stieltjes sum and the Riemann sum converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$; hence the two integrals are equal.